# Different block heights in tikzposter

Tags: block, height, tikzposter

In the code example attached, I have created 2 columns and 2 rows with blocks (see the figure below). The first column and first row, denoted "Test1a" gets a shorter height than the other four blocks.

[image: Figure illustrating one block getting a different height despite all blocks having the same settings]

I presume that I have missed something in the "settings".

The code is listed below:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,a0paper, subcolspace = 3 mm, colspace = 3 mm, landscape, innermargin = 3 mm,  margin = 7 mm, blockhorizontalspace = 5 mm, blockverticalspace = 5 mm, 25 pt]{tikzposter}


\usetheme{Envelope} % See Section 5 (Rätt okej!)
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{.495\textheight}
\makeatother

\settitle{ }

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{MidnightBlue!100}
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm, bodyoffsety=-2cm,bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,bodyinnersep = 3 mm,titleinnersep = 0em,roundedcorners=0]{}{\color{white} \flushleft  \fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont Test1a}

    \column{0.5}
    \colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{MidnightBlue!100}
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm, bodyoffsety=-2cm,bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,bodyinnersep = 3 mm,titleinnersep = 0em,roundedcorners=0]{}{\color{white} \flushleft  \fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont Test1b}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.3}
    \colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{MidnightBlue!100}
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm, bodyoffsety=-2cm,bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,bodyinnersep = 3 mm,titleinnersep = 0em,roundedcorners=0]{}{\color{white} \flushleft  \fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont Test2a}

    \column{0.7}
    \colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{MidnightBlue!100}
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm, bodyoffsety=-2cm,bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,bodyinnersep = 3 mm,titleinnersep = 0em,roundedcorners=0]{}{\color{white} \flushleft  \fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont Test2b}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Can, please, someone help me out with that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The problem seems to come from `\flushleft`

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how to get the text left adjusted and "ragged" on the right hand side without using `flushleft`. Without `flushleft` the text becomes "justified".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea why exactly, but it works with `\raggedright` instead of `\flushleft`.

Unrelated things:

- there is no `blockhorizontalspace` class option, so that setting of yours doesn't do anything.
- Instead of adding `\color{white}` everywhere, you can set `\colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white}`

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  usenames,
  dvipsnames,
  a2paper, 
  subcolspace = 3 mm,
  colspace = 3 mm,
  landscape,
  innermargin = 3 mm,
  margin = 7 mm,
%  blockhorizontalspace = 5 mm, % this is not a valid option, doesn't do anything
  blockverticalspace = 5 mm, 
  25 pt]{tikzposter}


\usetheme{Envelope} % See Section 5 (Rätt okej!)
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{.495\textheight}
\makeatother

\settitle{ }
\colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{MidnightBlue!100}
\colorlet{blockbodyfgcolor}{white} % color of text, no need for \color{white} everywhere
\begin{columns}
    \column{0.5}
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm,
           bodyoffsety=-2cm,
           bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,
           bodyinnersep = 3 mm,
           titleinnersep = 0em,
           roundedcorners=0]{}{\raggedright\fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont Test1a}

    \column{0.5}
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm,
           bodyoffsety=-2cm,
           bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,
           bodyinnersep = 3 mm,
           titleinnersep = 0em,
           roundedcorners=0]{}{\raggedright\fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont Test1b}
\end{columns}

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.3}
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm,
           bodyoffsety=-2cm,
           bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,
           bodyinnersep = 3 mm,
           titleinnersep = 0em,
           roundedcorners=0]{}{\raggedright\fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont Test2a}

    \column{0.7}
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm,
           bodyoffsety=-2cm,
           bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,
           bodyinnersep = 3 mm,
           titleinnersep = 0em,
           roundedcorners=0]{}{\raggedright \fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont Test2b}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting finding regarding `\raggedright`.

Comment: Thanks, regarding `blockhorizontalspace`. I just naïvely presumed there would exist a counterpart to `blockverticalspace`. I have some problem with vertical spacing of subcolumns, which probably was the reason for trying that. I will very well ask an official question about that as well soon tonight.

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson The two are implemented differently, but I cannot say what it is that causes the problem here. `flushleft` is (I believe) also implemented as an environment, so the intended usage is `\begin{flushleft} .. .\end{flushleft}`. That didn't seem to change anything for your example though.